# Tolist does not appear in Entity in windows form

Tags: c#, forms, entity

```
Data.CRM_DEMOEntities context = new Data.CRM_DEMOEntities();
```

I try to use

```
context.Customers.ToList();
```

However if i write,

**context.Customers.**

I see below things,

```
"Add"

"AsNoTracking"

"Attach"

"Create"

"Create<>"

"Find"

"Include"

"Local"

"Remove"

"SqlQuery"

"ToString"
```

Why there is no **ToList** , **Select** , **Where** etc ,in entity framework linq ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: context.Customers.create().Tolist()

Comment: You have to check the type of **Customers**. The ToList() method is an extention method on IEnumerable. Your Customers might be of type: SingleResult or something like that. Please give a bit more context on what technologies you are using etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you include the `System.Linq` namespace at the top of your file.

```
using System.Linq;
```